# How to write log outside app.Run context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I developed a web application using `NetCore 2.0`, inside the method `Configure` which every `ASP.NET` require, I have the following code:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Start");

            Thread t = new Thread(() => 
            {
                Start();
            });

            t.Start();
        });
    }
```

the code above write `Start` on the page and then execute the thread, I need to write content also on the `Start()` method and all other methods available in my application, how can I do that?

I cannot use the `context` object because is disposable.

For a practice example:

[image]

I need to write such content on the browser, there is a simple way to do that?

I'm not an expert on this type of application and I'm learning it.

Comment: You could just use the `loggerFactory` there since that won’t get disposed. But note that launching a thread like that on every request is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @poke I created a thread because the method `Start` execute different request, and when I launch the software loading the webpage without the thread this will display an infinite loading. Could you show me how to use loggerFactory across all classes? Which you propose for replace the thread logic? Thanks